# armature doesnot follow path after applying follow path constraint on armature object. The body separate from the armature

Tags: constraints

I face the problem with the follow path constraint which is when i set the armature to follow path constraint,it doest work but the body separate with the armature. Seek for help.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, you must have moved the mesh away from the armature, so it is not aligned with its armature anymore. The solution is to deactivate the armature *Follow Path* constraint visibility, bring the armature back to its *Rest Position*, and align back the mesh with the armature in the global space.